# Bank and Withdraw

Tags: c#, forms

I am completing an assignment for my C# level II class, and I need to make a program for withdrawing and depositing fund. This is the assignment description...

"Create a Windows app that functions like a banking account register. The GUI should initially allow the user to input the account name, number, and initial balance. Use separate inputs for first name, middle name, and last name. Check that the full name of the customer is entered and that only numeric values are entered in the number fields. Separate the business logic by creating a Customer class that includes Deposit and Withdrawal methods and an Update button. It should be impossible to do a Withdrawal and a Deposit at the same time. After each transaction, any amounts entered for Deposit or Withdrawal, etc. must be cleared before the next transaction."

so, far I've done most of the code, but when I set go to use the deposit or withdraw button, it send back the amount I entered, and didn't complete the adding or subtracting operations.

This is my first class

```
namespace Simple_Bank
{
    class Customer
    {
        private String account_Name;
        private long account_Number;
        private decimal account_Balance;

        public Customer()
        { }

        public Customer(String name, long number, decimal balance)
        {
            account_Name = name;
            account_Number = number;
            account_Balance = balance;
        }

        public string AccountName
        {
            get
            {
                return account_Name;
            }
            set
            {
                account_Name = value;
            }
        }

        public long AccountNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return account_Number;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("You must use numeric values");
                }
                else
                {
                    account_Number = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public decimal AccountBalance
        {
            get
            {
                return account_Balance;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("You must use numeric values");
                }
                else
                {
                    account_Balance = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            if(amount > 0)
            {
                account_Balance = account_Balance - amount;
                return;
            }
        }

        public void Deposit(decimal amount)
        {
            if(amount > 0)
            {
                account_Balance = account_Balance + amount;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is my second class form to complete the transaction with buttons

```
namespace Simple_Bank
{
    public partial class Process : Form
    {
        public Process()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customerAccount = new Customer();            
            customerAccount.Withdraw(Convert.ToDecimal(withdrawAmount.Text));
            labelBalance.Text = customerAccount.AccountBalance.ToString();
        }

        private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customerAccount = new Customer();
            customerAccount.Deposit(Convert.ToDecimal(depositAmount.Text));
            labelBalance.Text = customerAccount.AccountBalance.ToString();
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: In your click handlers, you always create a new customer, perform the operation and then immediately forget the customer again.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Customer each time you click one of your buttons. Your Customer has no name and a balance of 0, because you are using the empty constructor (You should probably remove that empty constructor).

So you are adding or subtracting your amount from 0.0 so the balance is always your amount at the end of your click method.

What you need is one Customer object, that is created at one time and then you can deposit or withdraw using this one customer object.